# How can I compare line from text file to multiple lines following?

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates, ifstream, sequential

I have a text file with 1s, 2s and 3s like below:

```
1
1
2
3
3
3
1
2
2
2
2
1
```

..and I am trying to find a way to find out how many in a row for each.

For example if I was checking 1 it would output:
1 in a row: 2, 2 in a row: 1, 3 in a row: 0, 4 in a row: 0....
all the way to 20 in a row (array size), since there is 2 1s in a row once and then 2 1s by themselves (only 1 in a row)

I am trying to calculate HOW MANY TIMES the number 1 is only 1 in a row, 2 in a row, 3 in a row, etc up to 20 (if i had a longer list)

So far this is what I have, however I don't know what to do at the ??? line:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream file("test.txt");
    string linebuffer;
    int sequenceCounts[20];
    int onez = 0;

    while (file && getline(file, linebuffer)){
        if (linebuffer.length() == 0)continue;
        {
            if (linebuffer == "1")
            {
                ??? while the next is 1->onez++
                sequenceCounts[onez]++;
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Phoenix which part do you not understand?

Comment: He is iterating through the file and wants to mark how many consecutive 1's 2's or 3's are in it. OP are you trying to find out which one has the most consecutive amount?

Comment: @Stupendous The confusion is between the *numbers to examine as strings* versus the *numbers representing counts* You could probably rewrite the question, pretending the file contains words instead of numbers ("dog", "dog", "cat", "bird", bird", bird", etc) and then give expected outputs for that example.

Comment: @TiStrga Goodies has it correct, I am trying to calculate how many consecutive 1s, or 2s or 3s are in it, so if there are 10 occurrences where there are 3 1s in a row, it will say 3 in a row: 10, however I am not trying to find which has the most consecutive amount but rather how often a certain consecutive amount happens. In fact: I don't necessarily NEED to even code this if there is already a website or program that would do this for me, I just didn't know how to word what I want so I wasn't able to find a online/offline tool to do this. I have a 12,000-line file which I want to use this 4.

Comment: @Stupendous Exactly.  Like I said, your example could be much more clear if you had used words (e.g., "three consecutive 'cat' in a row") versus counting numbers themselves.  Was just a suggestion for the wording of the question, not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of this:

```
int sequenceCounts[20];
int currentOnes = 0;

while (file && getline(file, linebuffer)){
  if (linebuffer.length() == 0){
    if (currentOnes > 0){
      sequenceCounts[currentOnes]++;
    }
    continue;
  }

  if (linebuffer == "1")
  {
    currentOnes++;  //We found another 1,
    //meaning the current group is bigger than in the last line.
  } else if (currentOnes > 0){
    //This line does not contain a "1", but the previous lines did
    sequenceCounts[currentOnes]++;
    currentOnes = 0;
  }
}
```

Basically each time you encounter a "1" you increase a counter how long your current sequence is. When the sequence is finished (a line without a "1" but with "1"s before) you increase the counter for that particular number of "1"s and reset your counter for the current sequence.

Edit: previous failed if the file ended with a "1"

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was trying to do and it seems so easy -_- I think I was overthinking things, going to try it out and get back to you, thanks in advanced.

Comment: For some reason when I run the code, using a for loop to output the array, it outputs -858993460 for every value.

Comment: did you initialize your array?

Comment: I'm stupid sorry, haven't used c++ in a couple years, thanks fixing now xD

Comment: This solution worked for me and was exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using a vector and a simple map to hold the longest consecutive streak, so you'd merely have to read the lines, parse them to ints, and add them to a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

int mostConsec(const std::vector<int> &vec) {
    std::map<int, size_t> consecMap;
    size_t count = 0;
    int current = vec.front();
    for (auto i : vec) {
        if (consecMap.count(current) == 0)
            consecMap[current] = 0;
        if (i == current) {
            count += 1;
            if (consecMap[current] <= count)
                consecMap[current] = count;
        }
        else {
            count = 1;
        }
        current = i;
    }
    auto ptr = std::max_element(
        consecMap.begin(),
        consecMap.end(),
        [](const std::pair<int, size_t> &p1, const std::pair<int, size_t> &p2) {return p1.second < p2.second; }
    );
    return ptr->first;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::ifstream inFile("test.txt");
    int tmp;
    while (inFile >> tmp)
        v.push_back(tmp);
    inFile.close();
    int most = mostConsec(v);
    std::cout << most << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```